# How do i generate JWT from a secretKey which was generated using "PBKDF2withHmacSHA256" in android?

Tags: android, pbkdf2, jjwt

So i am trying to generate **JWT** token from my key generated using **PBKDF2** and the code is like this in android:

```
public SecretKey generateKey(String passphraseOrPin) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        final int iterations = 5000;

        // Generate a 256-bit key
        final int outputKeyLength = 256;
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2withHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(getSha256Hash(passphraseOrPin).toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), iterations, outputKeyLength);
        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        return secretKey;
    }
```

But whenever i am trying to generate the token:

```
String jwtString = Jwts.builder().setSubject("sub").signWith(key, SignatureAlgorithm.HS256).compact();
```

i am getting the error:

```
Process: com.android.gocontract, PID: 7434
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.
        at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:111)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: io.jsonwebtoken.security.InvalidKeyException: The signing key's algorithm 'PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256' does not equal a valid HmacSHA* algorithm name and cannot be used with HS256.
        at io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm.assertValid(SignatureAlgorithm.java:358)
        at io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm.assertValidSigningKey(SignatureAlgorithm.java:302)
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.signWith(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:123)
        at com.android.gocontract.Activity.LoginActivity$2.onNext(LoginActivity.java:192)
        at com.android.gocontract.Activity.LoginActivity$2.onNext(LoginActivity.java:163)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onNext(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:58)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
        at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2019-09-23 18:38:37.036 7434-7434/com.android.gocontract I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7434 SIG: 9
```

the method to generate Sha256:

```
public String getSha256Hash(String password) {
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = null;
            try {
                digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            digest.reset();
            return bin2hex(digest.digest(password.getBytes()));
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

version of **jjwt**:

```
 api 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.10.7'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.10.7'
    runtimeOnly('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-orgjson:0.10.7') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json' //provided by Android natively
    }
```

Comment: There were problems with the case sensitivity in some versions of the library/android. Did you try using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 with the uppercase W? (you're using PBKDF2withHmacSHA256). Are you using the most recent version of the library?

Comment: what do you mean by the most recent version of library?

Comment: i just tried with the "W", so that's not the case i suppose

Comment: Which version of android and java you're using?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_191" and android would be up to date

Comment: PBKDF2withHmacSHA256 is only avaiable in API 26 and after. Are you using the correct api level?

Comment: but it's generating secret key, i have actually checked that it's Api 26+, but i am using minSdkVersion 23, could that be a reason??

Comment: It should work if the API is 26+. You can put a verification just in case. Use PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 for API 25-

Comment: I tested the algorithm here and it's working just fine, so probably is something with your getSha256Hash function or with your salt.

Comment: Posted sha256 method and also salt is just a text.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error, everything is working fine. The only thing I can think of is outdated version of the jwt library. Which version are you working with? (you can find it in your build.gradle, like 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.10.7')

Comment: we are using the same version i suppose, can you tell me what version of java you are using?? i have updated the jjwt version on the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199954/discussion-between-ricardo-a-and-fay007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution:** use another encryption algorithm, or use the lib [Spongy Castle](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle).

Useful lib: [Nimbus JOSE JWT Spongycastle](https://github.com/skynet67/Nimbus-JOSE-JWT-Spongycastle), if you need help mixing jwt with spongy castle.

**Why it's not working for you:** it is a particularity of the device you're using. Some devices support the PBKDF2withHmacSHA256 algorithm, while others don't.

**How I came to this conclusion:**
First I thought it could be a simple typo, but I found in the [JJWT](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/381) github that while the issue indeed existed, it was already fixed. Since the verification now uses equalsignorecase the typo wouldn't matter. You can confirm in the [code](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/jsonwebtoken/SignatureAlgorithm.java).

Then I thought it could be android or java version. But I discovered that [since java 8](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4638027) release it was already implemented.

I thought it could be the android version, but it works from [API 26](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory).

I've also tested the code you're using, and it worked just fine here, so it would not be any of these problems. Then I researched a lot, seen some [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256774/android-secretkeyfactory-problems-implementation-not-found), people having the same problem with [other libs](https://github.com/martinwithaar/Encryptor4j/issues/4) and other [algorithms](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences/issues/35).

**Extra:**
There is a code from [k3v](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15303291/5791681) that probably can help you (using Spongy Castle):

```
PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator generator = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator(new SHA256Digest());
generator.init(PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS5PasswordToUTF8Bytes(password), salt, iterations); 
KeyParameter key = (KeyParameter)generator.generateDerivedMacParameters(keySizeInBits);
```

Comment: Do i need to add Spongy Castle as library or i can i add it via gradle??

Comment: Via gradle is fine.

Comment: @Fay007 you need the following :
    implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.56.0.0'
    implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.56.0.0'
    implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.54.0.0'
    implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pg:1.54.0.0'